# How to convert JsonNode to Map

Tags: java, playframework, jackson, graphql

using play framework java on the server i'm using graphiql to make requests,
when i do `final JsonNode variables = request().body().asJson().get("variables")`, 
a JsonNode with a value 
`"{\"id\":\"bar\"}"`
 , now i want to convert this JsonNode to a Map,
i tried

```
Json.mapper().convertValue(variables, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        });
```

but i keep getting this exception

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.HashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]] from String value ('{"id":"bar"}'); no single-String constructor/factory method at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

What am i doing wrongly? how do i convert that JsonNode to a map?

Answer (score 0):

Change the type reference to use the `Map` interface instead of the `HashMap` class. So `new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>`.

Update:
Also, you said your JSON node has the value `"{\"id\":\"bar\"}"`. That's not a JSON object, that's a JSON string. Ensure your whole object looks like this:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "id":"bar"
  },
  "otherFields": ...
}
```

and not like this:

```
{
  "variables": "{\"id\":\"bar\"}",
  "otherFields": ...
}
```

Comment: similar error `Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.LinkedHashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]] from String value ('{"id":"bar"}'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
`